# How to query vm identifier and delete the vm using single query

Tags: vmware

I am using delete VMWare API which is working fine. For this I am querying the vm identifier first using the GET API with a filter `https://{vc}/rest/vcenter/vm?filter.names=test` and then use the vm identifier and delete the vm. Can we  not use a single API to delete the VM?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, that's not possible.

The only DELETE method available requires the VM identifier to be listed.